# Pocketsphinx Failed to calibrate voice activity detection

Tags: raspberry-pi, pocketsphinx

I have a problem with pocketsphinx, i have this error:

```
Error opening audio device default for capture: No such file or directory.
```

And when I start the command `arecord` i have this error arecord:

```
main 682 erreur à l'ouverture audio: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Can do you help me ? Please

**UPDATE:**

Now i have changed the `asound.conf` with this:

```
pcm.usb-audio {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
}

ctl.usb-audio {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
}
```

I have this error:

```
Warning: Could not find Mic element FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line 254: Failed to calibrate voice activity detection
```

Comment: now i have change the asound.conf with this: pcm.usb-audio {
 type hw
 card 0
 device 0
}     
ctl.usb-audio {
 type hw
 card 0
 device 0
}         I have this error : Warning: Could not find Mic element
FATAL_ERROR: "continuous.c", line 254: Failed to calibrate voice activity detection

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question to make it more readable and include all the information (please double-check the whitespace of the config file because it was lost in the comment). Check out the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how you can properly format your code yourself next time, and please use the editing function to update your post with new information instead of commenting, if the info is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are using very old version pocketsphinx-0.8 which indeed had this bug. It is recommended to compile latest version pocketsphinx-5prealpha, it will work reliably.

Comment: Thank you i test this tomorrow.

Comment: The sound when I test with espeak function but when i try to launch pocketshinx i have the error: Device or ressource busy

Comment: You need to build pocketsphinx with pulseaudio which does multiplexing probably or you need to configure alsa to do mixing for you.

Comment: This work fini with this command : pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plughw:0 -inmic yes. Thanks